# How to get int's from one .h to another .h

Tags: c++, variables, header-files

I have two header files, and I need some of the variables from header file 1 in header file 2.
Here is some info to help.

```
int SelRace, ...
char Race[80], ...
```

These two are from header file 1, and I need these values in header file 2 to follow if() statements.
In header file 1, SelRace is assigned 1, 2, or 3, and I'm trying to call on it again after that's been done. Here is where it is needed in header file 2.

```
while (1)
{
    if(SelRace == 1)
    {
        cout << "[text here]" << endl;
    }
        else if(SelRace == 2)
    {
        cout << "[text here]" << endl;
    }
        else if(SelRace == 3)
    {
        cout << "[text here]" << endl;
    }
        else
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Race[80] will be reprinted at various points in the [text here] as I have yet to fill those in. Depending on the value of SelRace, Race[80] also had a different string written to it.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should

- Define them in a `.cpp` as opposed to a `.h` as you are doing now.
- Declare them as extern in a `.h`
- Include above `.h` in the 2nd `.cpp`

Step 2 and 3 can be merged by declaring them as extern in the `.cpp` as billz suggests, depends on how widely you expect to use those globals.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put variable *definitions* in header files. If you do, then you can't include them in multiple source files, as the variable will have multiple definitions.

Instead put the *definitions* in a source file, and *declarations* in a header file. Then you can include the header file in all source files where you need to use the variable.

The *declaration* should be an `extern` declaration, like:

```
extern int SelRace;
extern char Race[80];
```

The `extern` keyword tells the compiler that the variable is defined in another place, so it can be properly referenced by the linker.

Answer (score 1):

you could define an extern variable in one header file and use it in another as follows

```
extern int SelRace;
```

Answer (score 0):

In header file, only declare function prototypes. Put definition in cpp file and make sure only one definition, but use `extern` if you need to use variables.

one.cpp

```
int SelRace, ...
char Race[80], ...
```

another.cpp

```
extern int SelRace, ...
extern char Race[80], ...
```

Function definitions which has your `while loop` should go to cpp file not header file.

Comment: Thank you for the help, as well, billz. You and Karthik helped.